# UISegemnted COntrol - selecting 3rd segment activates second segment

Tags: controls

I have a segmented control with 3 defined segments. i am looking to capture the segment index so I can use it in an if statement to update variables accordingly as such:

-(IBAction)numPlayers:(id)sender;
{
 numPlayersSegment = [(UISegmentedControl *)sender retain];
 if (numPlayersSegment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0)
 {
  numOfPlayers = 2;
 }
 else if (numPlayersSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 1)
 {
  numOfPlayers = 3;
 }
 else if (numPlayersSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = 2)
 {
  numOfPlayers = 4;
 }
 else if (numPlayersSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = -1)
 {
  numOfPlayers = 0;
 }

NSLog(@"Players selected = %d", numPlayersSegment.selectedSegmentIndex);

However whenever I press the third segment (index 2) it returns the value of the second segment (index 1) and also highlights the 2nd segment. I can see nothing untoward in IB.

Has anybody seen this and have any suggestions.

I am using xcode 3.2.1 on snow leopard

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`==` and `=`  don't function the same.  At a minimum you should fix that.  You also don't want the added `retain` to sender.